# Foreach loop incorrectly adding files to parent folder

Tags: powershell

The script below creates a folder of the IP address name, and adds 3 files into it. But it's also adding 3 files in the parent Logs folder.

Logs\10.2.2.1\3 files should be here, and they are, but those 3 files also show in \Logs folder.

```
$date = (Get-Date).AddDays(-1)

$str_yesterday = '20190902'

$exe = "D:\task-scripts\7z.exe"

foreach ($IP in Get-Content D:\serverlist\list.txt) {
    New-Item -ItemType Directory -Force -Path D:\LOG\$str_yesterday\$IP
    $file = New-Item -ItemType file "D:\LOG\$str_yesterday\$IP\$str_yesterday-log.txt" -Force
    $date_MSG = &$exe a -r D:\LOG\$str_yesterday\$IP\MSG_$str_yesterday.zip \\$IP\$str_yesterday
    $data_Server = &$exe a -r D:\LOG\$str_yesterday\$IP\Server_$str_yesterday.zip \\$IP\$str_yesterday
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the file: `D:\serverlist\list.txt`

Is there a newline (blank line) at the end of the file? i.e. when you do the `foreach` loop, a blank line will set `$IP` to blank, which will change the path to:

```
"D:\LOG\$str_yesterday\\$str_yesterday-log.txt"
```

PowerShell will ignore the second slash and put the file at the root folder.

Comment: In addition, you can skip empty or whitespace-only lines using `foreach ($IP in (Get-Content D:\serverlist\list.txt | Where-Object { $_ -match '\S'})) {`

Comment: yup, there was a blank space. Silly mistakes. Thanks alot!.. And ty Theo, I've added that bit of code to prevent future mistakes.